# Process synchronization using counting semaphores

Tags: operating-system, synchronization, semaphore

I have a question regarding counting semaphores and I want to whether my implementation is right or if it deadlocks somewhere.

There are 5 processes, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5 that need to be executed in the following order:

```
P2 and P3 must execute after P1 completes.
    • P4 must execute after both P2 and P3 complete.
    • P5 must execute after both P2 and P3 complete.
```

MY APPROACH: What I'm thinking is say there are two counting semaphores S1 and S2. P2 and P3 wait on S1, and P4 and P5 wait on S2. Initially both have a value 0. After P1 completes its execution, its posts twice on S1, incrementing its value to 2. Then P2 and P3 can execute. P4 and P5 must acquire S2 twice. So, after P2 and P3 complete, both of them together post two times on S2, incrementing its value to 2, and so P4 and P5 can execute.

Is this right? OR does it deadlock in some case?

Comment: It is right, but depending on OS, there are other ways... The question you would encounter with semaphores would be who initializes them and how/when processes start using them.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk Could you give me an example where my solution deadlocks?

Comment: You don't define strictly when the semaphores are initialized. If that is a precondition, your solution would work.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk I am confused as to when to initialize the semaphores to avoid any deadlock conditions. Could you help me on that?

Comment: Add the following: process P0 creates semaphores with values of 0, an then starts processes P1-P5 in arbitrary order (but after semaphore initialization).

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk Is it possible to do this without adding any other extra constraints i.e., the P0 one?

Comment: It becomes platform-dependent. Not all platforms allow definition of shared objects "in place". And your semaphores are shared objects, which makes their operation non-trivial. For example, we know that software fails sometimes. How to handle recovery in this case? Who restarts the process, how owned locks are recycled? So, at the first glance, your sequence is correct. But if you add there "usual" process-level problems, than it would become pretty difficult to manage and/or troubleshoot.